# Cannot render_template after POST using JavaScript and Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, sockets, flask

I'm making a website using Flask, and I wanted to add a progress bar so that after I'm submitting a form it'll show a progress bar. I'm adapting the code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUfUKtJqaxQ&t=2s&ab_channel=Pingcode in order to do that. It's combining JavaScript, Socket library, and Flask. The progress bar works perfectly, but after it finishes it's process, I can't redirect or render_template to a new URL.

This is the code for the Flask.

```
import time
import numpy as np
from asyncio import sleep
from website import create_app
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask import render_template, Response, redirect, url_for

app = create_app()
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/progress', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def progress():
    multiplier = np.random.randint(35, 100)
    my_list = [0] * multiplier
    for x in range(len(my_list)+1):
        socketio.emit("update progress", x * (100 / len(my_list)))
        time.sleep(0.3)
    return render_template('result.html', multiplier=multiplier)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app=app, debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=3002)
```

And this is the code for the HTML template and JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Progress Bar</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.3/socket.io.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-WPFUvHkB1aHA5TDSZi6xtDgkF0wXJcIIxXhC6h8OT8EH3fC5PWro5pWJ1THjcfEi"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            const socket = io();
            socket.connect("https://localhost:3002");

            let progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
            let btn = document.getElementById("submit-button");

            socket.on("connect", function() {
                console.log("Connected");
            })

            socket.on("update progress", function(percent) {
                console.log("Get percent: " + percent);
                progressBar.style.width = percent + "%";

                btn.disabled = true;
                btn.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
                btn.style.border = "none";
                btn.cursor = "not-allowed";

            })
            
            let mainForm = document.getElementById("mainForm");
            mainForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
                event.preventDefault();
                fetch("/progress", {
                    method: "POST"
                })
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <form id="mainForm" method="POST">
        <h1>Progress!</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" id="progressBar" role="progressbar"></div>
            </div>
            <input id="submit-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

There are no errors but my program stops after the progress bar finished. Please kindly check what I missed, and thanks in advance.